# How can I store and manipulate text input upon pressing enter?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to store text input upon pressing enter which is not working for me. Not even an alert goes off when I press enter.

Here is my current simplified code:

```
const ToDo = () => {
  const saveValueFunction = (e: any) => {
    console.debug(e.keyCode)
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
      AsyncStorage.setItem('any_key_here', e)
      alert('Data Saved')
    }
  }

  const [value, onChangeText] = React.useState('')
  return (
    <TextInput
      placeholder="Add a Task"
      placeholderTextColor="aqua"
      color="aqua"
      backgroundColor="#262626"
      style={styles.textInput}
      onChange={(e) => onChangeText(e.target.value)}
      value={value}
      onKeyDown={(e) => saveValueFunction(e)}
    />
  )
}
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you, I just tried it. Unfortunately it didn't work and now it's not sending me alerts at all. I have updated the code with your recommendation, and would appreciate if you could look at it again. if I have time later on I will see if I can try to wrap it inside a form

Comment: You pass ```event``` in your ```saveValueFunction``` but check for ```e```. Isn't ```e``` undefined in this context?

Comment: I cannot import html, I used `import {  TextInput } from 'react-native;`. I just tried plugging your code into mine again and it still doesn't give me any alerts from pressing enter, I don't know why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`onKeyPress`](https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput.html#onkeypress) which is called when any key is pressed. It is called with Native event which has `key` property which holds values like `Enter`, `Backspace` or the character typed by the user. So you can compare it with `Enter` to detect the Enter pressed by the user.

```
const [value, setValue] = React.useState('');
const handleKeyPress = e => {
  if (e.key === 'Enter') {
    AsyncStorage.setItem('any_key_here', value);
    setValue('');
    showAlert();
    alert(`Task saved: ${value}`);
  }
};

<TextInput
  value={value}
  onChangeText={text => setValue(text)}
  onKeyPress={e => handleKeyPress(e)}
  placeholder="Add a Task"
  placeholderTextColor="aqua"
  color="aqua"
  backgroundColor="pink"
  style={styles.textInput}
/>
```

Code Playground: [Expo](https://snack.expo.io/@iamajeets/text-input-so)

Comment: https://snack.expo.io/Wh0IRZECy 
Here is my full code, it causes an error on snack but apparently not on my local program. On my local program though, it still does not give me an alert when the enter key is pressed. Thank you so much for spending this much time on my code! I really appreciate it

Comment: https://snack.expo.io/o6vSmwMIGt
Thank you, it doesn't show an error now but it still doesn't work. On snack it won't let me type anything, but on my local file pressing enter doesn't do anything. If you try running it on your device, pressing enter just brings the keyboard down but does not seem to run the function

Comment: Also,if you want to show `Alert` on mobile devices, check [this](https://reactnative.dev/docs/alert). [This](https://snack.expo.io/@iamajeets/alert-function-component-example) snack shows how to use `Alert`but i think it will only work on mobile, not on web. You need to learn react-native :) I am also not expert of it.

Comment: I upvoted (but I'm a new user so it doesn't seem to count) but may I ask how to clear the text input?

Answer (score 0):

```
const [inputData, setInputData] = useState('');
const [includeds, setIncludeds] = useState([]);

 const handleChange = (e: any) => {
    setInputData(e.target.value);
  };

const onKeyPressEvent = (e: any) => {
      if (e.key === 'Enter') {
        if (
          includeds &&
          includeds.length < MAX_INCLUDES &&
          (inputData && inputData.length !== 0)
        ) {
          e.persist();
          setIncludeds(arr => [...arr, inputData]);
          setInputData('');
        }
      }
    }


return(
         <input
          onChange={e => handleChange(e)}
          onKeyDown={e => onKeyPressEvent(e)}
        />
 )
```

You can basically do something like this.You should implement your case on top of this code.

Comment: you will store your entries in an array.

Comment: Thank you! I tried this just now and nothing happens when I press enter.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `onSubmitEditing={}` prop in text input and call the save function inside the curly brackets.